# How to detect subscriber's queue is full (and messages are thrown away)

Tags: ros, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a newbie ros user.

[According to tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(c%2B%2B)#roscpp_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingPublisherSubscriber.The_Code_Explained-1), messages may disappear if the subscriber's queue is full.

I need to know if the message is lost. Is it possible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244077/how-to-detect-subscriber%27s-queue-is-full-(and-messages-are-thrown-away)/) by [LWisteria](https://answers.ros.org/users/28025/lwisteria/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-09-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I see you linked to a roscpp tutorial.

If you want to see if a message is being dropped, you can set the subscribing node's logger level to DEBUG and look for the message ["Incoming queue was full for topic"](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/kinetic-devel/clients/roscpp/src/libros/subscription_queue.cpp#L67)

I don't see a way to check that programmatically.

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2016-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on 2016-09-22**:
or you can add a piece of code in the callback function : to check whether the queue is full and print something.But that's just a double work.